# Who can initiate the legal proceedings for hacking?

Tags: united-kingdom, hacking, computer-misuse-act

If a server is owned and maintained by Organization A, but almost fully installed and configured by Person A, who is a employee of Organization A, then who initiates the legal proceedings regarding unauthorized access, if person B gets access without authorization?

Furthermore, if Person B gets into the server without consent of Person A, but with the consent of Organization A, what is the stance on that? Can Person A take Person B to court, or does the Organization overrule that due to ownership?

Answer (score 1):

If the unauthorized access constitutes a crime, then typically it is the state (i.e., a public prosecutor) who initiates prosecution of the crime.

Anybody who claims damages [can start a civil legal proceeding](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/235/10).